# Series convergence and its reciprocal

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $\sum \frac{1}{a_n}$ diverges to $\infty$

If $\sum a_n$ diverges, then for every $M > 0$ $\exists$ $n$ such that $s_n > M$

^ Are the statements above true? I'm not given any information about $a_n$, which is a series. $s_n$ denotes a partial sum of the series. I have no idea about the second one, but for the first one I'm pretty sure you can assume that any series that converges will not have its reciprocal converge, for example $\frac{1}{x^2}$ converges, but $x^2$ does not. The second one seems to be a question about whether there's a limit to the sequence, and again I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Neither statement is true for a general sequence $a_n$.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ converges, then $a_n \to 0$, so $1/a_n \not\to 0$.  So $\sum 1/a_n$ diverges.  This is not to say $\sum 1/a_n$ diverges to $\infty$, however.

Comment: Are you supposed to assume $a_n \ge 0$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael there are no assumptions to $a_n$. Nothing is known about them.

Comment: If someone can give a short answer (just like a 2 sentence explanation) then I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample for (1): $a_n = -1/2^n$. $\sum_n 1/a_n$ diverges to $-\infty$, not $+\infty$, and $s_n < 0$.

Counterexample for (2): $a_n = -1$.  All $s_n \le 0$.